# I need to get data under FirebaseAuthentication user Id in my Firebase database using android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

//this is the method where I try to retrieve data

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    String uid = (String) firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();`//setting auth uid to uid variable`

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("profiles").child(uid);
```

//using addValue Event Listner

```
databaseReference.child("users").child("profiles").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String name = (String)dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue();
            text.setText(name);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

//this is my database

users

```
 profiles
  GUiQKxqij3bv4wRCaBcMuN6UNlD3
    address:"Mount Lavinia"
    name:"Hemal Herath"
    tel:"0702221617"
    url:"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/csa..."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
databaseReference.child("users").child("profiles").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         for (DataSnapshot singleSnapShot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    switch(singleSnapShot.getKey())
                    {
                        case "address":
                            addressText.setText(singleSnapShot.getValue());
                            break;
                        case "name":
                            nameText.setText(singleSnapShot.getvalue());
                            break;
                        case "tel":
                            telText.setText(singleSnapShot.getvalue());
                            break;
                        case "url":
                            urlText.setText(singleSnapShot.getvalue());
                            break;
                    }
                }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing? Do you have the data in the dataSnapshot?

Comment: I try to use your code but they are not appear in TextViews. all Blank

Comment: You need to make sure if datasnapshot object has the value from the firebase database?

Comment: how can i do that please help me im new to firebase

Comment: Datasnapshot object will contains the firebase data at the particular UID as per your firebase reference.  You can hover over the datasnapshot(in debug mode) to see if it has the data. Plus check if you have specified the correct UID ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149622/discussion-between-vivek-verma-and-hemalherath).

Comment: Go and see this link.Tou can send FCM token like this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MYgZQjX7N0&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hjxP_CHAhjXQN3zrcEhluF_